# Change JMX port in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

I´m using Spring boot, and trying to run two instances in a Same machine, but I´m having a bind port issue in the `com.sun.management.jmxremote.port` 
I´m looking in all documentation and all around internet and I cannot find the way to change that property `com.sun.management.jmxremote.port`

my `application.properties` looks like this

```
server.port = 8094
spring.application.name = F2e-spring-boot-mock
management.jmxremote.port=9003
```

I also I tried with   `com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9001` and nothing.

I´m using Spring boot maven plugin.

When I run Spring boot I always see this logs

```
# system properties
    "com" : {
        # system properties
        "sun" : {
            # system properties
            "management" : {
                # system properties
                "jmxremote" : {
                    # system properties
                    "authenticate" : "false",
                    # system properties
                    "port" : "9001",
                    # system properties
                    "ssl" : "false"
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Regards.

Comment: did you try jmx.rmi.port

Comment: yep, but nothing